# What is a complete list of Exceptions that can be thrown by shutil.rmtree

Tags: python, shutil

I am using the rmtree method from shutil in Python (2.7).

What are all possible exceptions that can occur while calling this method?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with reading the docs? [shutil](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html)

Comment: @Jakob I read them, but couldn't figure out from there which errors could be thrown.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the implementation, you'll have to check `OSError`.
But you can use the argument `ignore_errors=True` on call to...ignore errors ;) or give a callback `onerror` that will check the exceptions during the execution of file removal. ([cf shutil.rmtree documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree))

Answer (score 3):

Unless you do something very funky, `os.error` and `OSError`

Comment: os.error is an alias for OSError ;) (http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.error)

Comment: @Cédric: interesting, I didn't know that. Curiously, `rmtree` tries to catch both, in different places. Maybe it's some kind of a historic artifact